# How can I get my application to run with Administrative rights for office 365 connexion (API REST Graph) when I don't have them myself?

Tags: c#, rest, office365

I am currently developing a web application with an MVC architecture in C # by following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial

The problem is that I use permissions that only an Administrator can validate, so when I click to authenticate, an Administrator must use his account to validate the application, then I reconnect with my account to do my tests. 
Every time I recompile, the admin must validate again.

Since I compile very often and I do not have(and can not have) admin rights, I would like to find a way to automate the resolution of this problem

If the admin must put an id and a password in the code, they want to make sure that I can not see it.

Is there a specific right to handle this?

Comment: My administrator tried to give me all possible rights and it is only by passing me in general admin that I can validate the application and I did not try anything in code because I have absolutely no idea of what to do... (of course i can't be a general admin)

Comment: Someone has an idea of what to do ??